# Getting "Non-successful status code 502" error when reverse geocoding of large data in GeoPy

Tags: python, reverse-geocoding, big-data, geopy

I have a data size of 1.87GB containing 14962000 rows and 9 columns. And I want to apply GeoPy but I got the errors.

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd 
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter

df = pd.read_csv("mydata_name.csv")

df["Geo"] = df["latitude"].astype(str)+ ',' + df["longitude"].astype(str)
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="MyApp", timeout=10)

rgeocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.reverse, min_delay_seconds=0.001)

df['address'] = df['Geo'].apply(rgeocode)
```

When executing my code I get the following errors. I want to get an address for all rows. But the code takes 5 hours to execute and I get this:

```
RateLimiter caught an error, retrying (0/2 tries). Called with (*('24.807412,46.803666',), **{}).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 360, in _call_geocoder
    result = self.adapter.get_json(url, timeout=timeout, headers=req_headers)
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\adapters.py", line 373, in get_json
    resp = self._request(url, timeout=timeout, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\adapters.py", line 401, in _request
    raise AdapterHTTPError(
geopy.adapters.AdapterHTTPError: Non-successful status code 502

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\extra\rate_limiter.py", line 136, in _retries_gen
    yield i  # Run the function.
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\extra\rate_limiter.py", line 274, in __call__
    res = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\nominatim.py", line 359, in reverse
    return self._call_geocoder(url, callback, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 378, in _call_geocoder
    self._adapter_error_handler(error)
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 392, in _adapter_error_handler
    raise exc_cls(str(error)) from error
geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: Non-successful status code 502
RateLimiter caught an error, retrying (0/2 tries). Called with (*('24.650473,46.669335',), **{}).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 360, in _call_geocoder
    result = self.adapter.get_json(url, timeout=timeout, headers=req_headers)
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\adapters.py", line 373, in get_json
    resp = self._request(url, timeout=timeout, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\adapters.py", line 401, in _request
    raise AdapterHTTPError(
geopy.adapters.AdapterHTTPError: Non-successful status code 502

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\extra\rate_limiter.py", line 136, in _retries_gen
    yield i  # Run the function.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks okay to me. The only thing that I suggest is to wrap your geocoding procedure into a [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), i.e.

```py
from geopy.point import Point

def reverse_geocoding(lat, long):
    point = Point(lat, lon)
    try:
        location = locator.reverse(point)
        return location.raw
    except (AttributeError, KeyError, ValueError):
        return f"No result for {point}"
```

Regarding the [502 Bad Gateway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502) error:

> ```
> GeocoderServiceError: Non-successful status code 502
> ```

it can occur because of several reasons:

1. As mentioned in [the Nominatim's documentation](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/#requirements):

   > No heavy uses (an absolute maximum of 1 request per second).

   So, you probably exceeded **the daily limit, which is 86400 requests per day** (1sec * 60 * 60 * 24).

   > The easiest way to guarantee you don't make more than one request per
   > second is
   >
   > ```
   > time.sleep(1)
   > ```
   >
   > while interacting through the requests, before making a request.

   In total it might be needed about 174 days for proceeding 14962000 rows.
2. Another assumption (which is less likely) is that the web service stopped working. It was described in [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/499).

---

**References:**

- [Reverse geocoding with Python Nominatim limitations & improvement geopy.geocoders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55084923/5791355)
- [geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: Non-successful status code 502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69707013/geopy-exc-geocoderserviceerror-non-successful-status-code-502)
- [Exception Handling in Pandas .apply() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847304/exception-handling-in-pandas-apply-function)

Comment: Why does AttributeError, KeyError, ValueError work here when the error says AdapterHTTPError?

Answer (score 1):

An [HTTP 502](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) status implies something went wrong in your internet connection, it's possible you exceeded some limit on the geocoder.

Comment: Thanks for response. How can I know the maximum limits

Comment: That would probably be covered in the documentation